# Magento Import CSV stock Availability

Tags: magento, csv

I have create a csv file, 
and import to magento 
to update the Stock Availability.

sku,qty,is_in_stock

Prod1,200,1

But it just create the product and update the qty, it cant update the Stock Availability, it still "out of stock"

Would i have missed something?

Comment: Napoleon,from where you was update stock....???

Comment: Please re indexing from index maneagement

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure that "Manage Stock" is in "Yes" state then importing could change the availability of products.